# How to use jquery in project?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am new to jquery.I want to ask u ,if I want to use jquery in my web application,do I need to download library from 
https://jquery.com/download/
Which one uncompressed/Compressesed, development jQuery 1.12.2?What is CDN?How safe to use jquery from CDN like this?

```
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
```

Is it  default CDN : http://code.jquery.com?

Comment: it depends , it will be downloaded from the server if you use code.jquery when there is no connectivity it may fail, if you download and use it in your app then this will work seamless without the consideration of the Net Connectivity , no its not default cdn , you need to keep the version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CDN are very good to use This is because: -

- It increases the parallelism available. (Most browsers will only
  download 3 or 4 files at a time from any given site.)
- It increases the chance that there will be a cache-hit. (As more
  sites follow this practice, more users already have the file ready.)
- It ensures that the payload will be as small as possible. (Google can
  pre-compress the file in a wide array of formats (like GZIP or
  DEFLATE). This makes the time-to-download very small, because it is
  super compressed and it isn't compressed on the fly.)
- It reduces the amount of bandwidth used by your server. (Google is
  basically offering free bandwidth.)
- It ensures that the user will get a geographically close response.
  (Google has servers all over the world, further decreasing the
  latency.)
- (Optional) They will automatically keep your scripts up to date. (If
  you like to "fly by the seat of your pants," you can always use the
  latest version of any script that they offer. These could fix
  security holes, but generally just break your stuff.)

**How To Access Asp.net Controls in Jquery**

```
$('#<%= myTextBox.ClientID %>')
```

here myTextBox is id of Asp.net textbox server control

**SEE THE JQUERY CDN BELOW THAT IS DEMO FOR USING JQUERY ON WEBSITE**

```js
//    button click
    $("#click").click(function(){
       alert($('#Hello').text());
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span style="display:none;" id="Hello">Hello ! This is Jquery</span>
<input type="button" id="click" Value ="Knock Here" />
```

Comment: Hi Heemanshu,thanks for ur help.Instead of html control can I use server control ?Instead of html button can I use asp button  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />

Comment: @JuiTest Hi , yes sure you can use asp.net controls I added that part in my answer recently

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the Website. If it is a small website, You can't afford to have CDN servers (CDN servers will improve the network I/O speed). In that case, you can use the other CDN servers which provides this jQuery resource from the mirror servers which eventually helps to speed up your web page loading.

But in case you have big website and have enough resource providers (CDN), you have to download and serve it from your server to remove the dependency from other servers.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply Thanga.

Answer (score 1):

If you are building a web application to be used internally, then don't use CDN as your servers will be faster, it it is a public web site then use CDN and reference the .min file, you can use Google or Microsoft CDN, they are all safe